# Circular Progress Bar shows on scroll - issues with percentage text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot seem to get the value (text) in the center to be 100% - instead, if the value is set to `100%` it shows `00%`.

Here is what I have: [Demo / fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1f58u1o5/31/)

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  function animateElements() {
    $('.progressbar').each(function() {
      var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
      var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
      var percent = $(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
      var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
      var animate = $(this).data('animate');
      if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() - 30 && !animate) {
        $(this).data('animate', true);
        $(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
          startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
          value: percentage,
          thickness: 14,
          fill: {
            color: '#1B58B8'
          }
        }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
          $(this).find('div').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2) + '%');
        }).stop();
      }
    });
  }

  // Show animated elements
  animateElements();
  $(window).scroll(animateElements);
});
```

```css
.progressbar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 25px;
}
.circle {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.circle canvas {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.circle div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.circle strong i {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.circle span {
  display: block;
  color: #aaa;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;height:800px;">↓ Scroll down ↓</div>

<h3>Title (Placeholder)</h3>

<div class="progressbar" data-animate="false">
  <div class="circle" data-percent="100">
    <div></div>
    <p>Testing</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar" data-animate="false">
  <div class="circle" data-percent="30">
    <div></div>
    <p>Testing</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar" data-animate="false">
  <div class="circle" data-percent="77">
    <div></div>
    <p>Testing</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar" data-animate="false">
  <div class="circle" data-percent="49">
    <div></div>
    <p>Testing</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
$(this).find('div').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2) + '%');
```

It will never allow for the percent string to be longer than 2 characters. A proper fix would involve converting the values rather than truncating the leading values.

A cheap solution would be to check for the value to be "00" and convert it to 100, something like:

```
 $(this).find('div').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2) + '%');
 if(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2) == "00"){
     $(this).find('div').text('100%');
 }
```

**Update**

Thanks to SteveMitcham for his comment, you could also just replace the line with:

```
$(this).find('div').text((stepValue*100).toFixed(0) + "%");
```

Comment: $(this).find('div').text((stepValue*100).toFixed(0) + "%"); works as well without the need for the special case for 100%

Comment: @SteveMitcham Perfect! I was looking for a way to do that and couldn't quite get it. Updating my answer.

Comment: @Steve, your solution is actually better!  I do have one last question though - how can I implement decimals? For example: 99.8%

Comment: Change the toFixed parameter to have the number of decimals that you want.

Comment: `toFixed(2)` is what I originally had - however, if I implement in the data-percentage in html: 99.8 - it only renders as 99%

Comment: @Hybrid The problem is with your `percentage` variable. You parse it as an int, therefor removing any floating points after it. Id you use `var percentage = percent/100;` you'll get the desired result, but then all of them have .0 after them.

Comment: Fixed: `value: percentage` needed to be `value: percent / 100` - It does have the decimal point after each one, but I think it's okay!

Comment: Thank you everyone (especially sharf & Steve) for all your help!